# Best way of getting path to "Application Data" directory?

Tags: winapi, path

There are several possible ways of getting the path to the application data directory:

- using the `%APPDATA%` environment variable
- calling `SHGetFolderPath` with `CSIDL_APPDATA`

What is the best way to get the path from within an program? Are there any gotchas when I use the environment variable?

Which method is safest across XP, Vista and upcoming versions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest that calling `SHGetFolderPath()` is the most appropriate, and portable method; the alternatives, such as reading an environment variable, or (worse) trying to extract it from the registry are likely to trip you up in the future.

[Raymond Chen has an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/03/55532.aspx) explaining why pulling such paths from the registry is a bad idea.

Comment: I read the article, and I previously I did exactly what the article told me *not* to do:)

Answer (score 12):

```
    string appDataPath = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

You'll need to use the GetFolderPath method get the actual path as Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData is just an enum.

Answer (score 0):

If you're programming in .NET you can use this:

```
string appDataPath = Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData;
```

Comment: SpecialFolder.ApplicationData is an enum, not a path. Use Environment.GetFolderPath as shown in @jMM's answer

Answer (score 0):

One important difference in Python: in case of unicode file paths `ctypes.windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW` returns a unicode string, whereas`os.environ['APPDATA']` returns a byte string.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was wondering, in Ruby the command would look like the following:

```
appDataPath = ENV['APPDATA']
```